# Website not scrolling on Galaxy S4 and later versions (Android)

Tags: android, css, wordpress, mobile

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site and am having an issue specifically with Galaxy S4 and other versions. It seems to work fine on all other mobile devices, on multiple mobile browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.) After doing some research I've seen a couple of people having the same issue but no real answer to the problem.

The issue even recreates with emulators built into the desktop browsers, so I have tested it on multiple version of Galaxy using Chromes emulator and the same issue occurs as on the hardware device.

Here is the link to the site I am working on: http://beta.iqcando.com/

I'm truly at a loss as to what could be causing this, as it appears to be fully mobile on other devices. Any suggestions or solutions are welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an

```
overflow-y: hidden!important;
```

on your `html` in `style.css` on line 109.

When you remove that the scroll works fine ;)

If you want to debug your site on mobile, on chrome you can install sdk and then use chrome to inspect the mobile version of your site.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly it, I should've never assumed that the css in parent theme wasn't what was causing the issue. I'll make use of the link you provided as well.